# How to negate a regex inside another regex

Tags: regular-expression, posix

That is, given a POSIX regex X, what POSIX regex is the complementary of X? (in a more detailed way: how to get regex X' that matches all strings that are not matched by X, but doesn't match any string that is matched by X)

If this is not available in POSIX, is there a common extension that has it?

Comment: PCREs (perl) can do that.

Comment: @HaukeLaging they can? How? Do you mean `$foo!~/bar/`?

Comment: The problem doesn't usually come up, as in most environments you can just `if not match` instead of `if match` so you use the same regexp. Your question would be easier to answer if you had a specific use case.

Comment: @terdon I am not familiar with PCRE. I just know they can but not how. If I knew I would have mentioned it. My fuzzy memory believes that `?` is involved (like in bash extglob).

Comment: @frostschutz That doesn't help you at all if you need the negation within a regex.

Comment: Could you give us an example of why you would want this? I am still not entirely sure I understand what you are looking for.

Comment: @terdon I wanted it yesterday for something within aptitude search, but I am not sure anymore what (and I am aware of ?not there). Anyway, it's a general question. There are probably workarounds to many particular examples, but that's not what I was looking for

Comment: @terdon, since you asked for an example, here is something practical I just needed: I want to _walk_ a directory structure to record its contents, but I want to filter out every file in directory foo, except for file foo/bar. Let COMPL(X) be the complement of X, for any regex X. A solution is then `find dir -printf %P\\n | sort | grep -P "foo/bar|COMPL(foo)"`. Using the concrete solution I selected below: `find dir -printf %P\\n | sort | grep -P 'foo/bar|^(?:(?!foo).)*$'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you could try `(?:(?!X).)` with PCRE, It definitely works when `X` is a string but I am not a 100% sure that it would work all the time when `X` is a regex.

```
echo "dust mite" | grep -P '^(?:(?!abc).)*$'
dust mite

echo "dust abc mite" | grep -P '^(?:(?!abc).)*$'
echo "dust mite" | grep -P '^(?:(?!abc(x+y)).)*$'
dust mite

echo "dust abcxxxxy mite" | grep -P '^(?:(?!abc(x+y)).)*$'
```

Comment: I gave it a few tries and it seems to work too! Thanks a lot. I find it strange there isn't a simpler way though! It looks to me like it would be the easiest thing to implement... and very useful - guaranteeing this would be possible everywhere using just POSIX regex, without having to rely on other particular command constructs (like grep's -v)

Comment: BTW, I would vote you up, but I don't have enough rep, sorry

Comment: Traditional regexes are just a simple state machine.  There is an abundance of background information on the Internet which explains fairly well how a regex fundamentally works.  Once you understand that, it will also be fairly obvious why the Perl (and thus PCRE) extension is not standard.

Comment: @tripleee: I did not ask why PCRE is not standard, I ask why wasn't a simple a complement operator included in available regexes (even in PCRE). The way I see it, regexes are fundamentally based on Finite State Machines (FSM) and it would be a trivial thing to get a complementary FSM for any given regex FSM. So, perhaps from the abundant information on how regex fundamentally work you could select the pieces that would actually contribute anything to the discussion?